# detox app could not be found, did you run './gradlew assembleAndroidTest'?

Tags: react-native, mocha.js, jestjs, detox

I am doing detox test for react native android version 0.57. I am getting this error.

Error is

> Error: 'D:\folder\android\app\build\outputs\apk\androidTest\dev\debug\app-dev-debug-androidTest.apk' could not be found, did you run './gradlew assembleAndroidTest' ?

Package.json

```
"android.emu.debug": {
"binaryPath": "android/app/build/outputs/apk/dev/debug/app-dev-debug.apk",
"build": "cd android && .\\gradlew assembleDebug assembleAndroidTest -DtestBuildType=debug && cd ..",
"type": "android.attached",
"name": "192.168.83.101:5555"
```

}

Error picture
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This error is usually caused but not having built the test apk. It can usually be resolved by running

```
detox build -c android.emu.debug
```

If you make changes to your application you should always run the above script before running any test.

I usually run the following script to make sure that the build is uptodate before testing.

```
detox build -c android.emu.debug && detox test -c android.emu.debug
```

Comment: Thank you, if I run without build I got this error. If I do " detox build -c android.emu.debug && detox test -c android.emu.debug ", metro bundler is not opening so test is throwing error. currently I am running two commands react-native run-android and detox test -c android.emu.debug it is working

Comment: How to do detox test for popup message. ex : For auto pick OTP we ask user permission to allow or deny permission in react native android , how to deny permission in detox ?

Comment: I am not sure why the metro bundler isn't starting. That is the command I use and it starts for me, and that is with a vanilla detox setup. You can always run the metro bundler by running `npm start` before you run `detox build ...`

Comment: https://github.com/wix/detox/blob/master/docs/APIRef.DeviceObjectAPI.md#2-set-runtime-permissions There are also other methods that you can use to find items in the view hierarchy. I suggest you take some time and read through the docs so that you know what Detox is capable of and what it is not.

Comment: Thank you, I will go through documentation

Answer (score 6):

Detox has strange behavior where it mutates your path to your apk, if you specify it using `binaryPath`.

To specify the exact path to your apk, add an entry for `testBinaryPath` that points to the APK you want Detox to use.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer! Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

change path `android/app/build/outputs/apk/dev/debug/app-dev-debug.apk` to `android/app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk`
and detox automatically will create apk to path `android/app/build/outputs/apk/AndroidTest/debug/app-debug-androidTest.apk`